# Torquing pinion nut on pinion shaft—can it be done with tires on ground?

Tags: jeep, wrangler, front-differential, drive-shaft

I am about to install a 1310 driveshaft on a '15 Jeep Wrangler; it requires replacing the front pinion yoke. The Wrangler has a lift kit which allows me to crawl under and work with plenty of room. I have all the proper tools (click type ft.-lb. torque wrench, dial type in.-lb. torque wrench, etc.).

Simple question: can I remove and also torque the pinion nut (to 160 lb.-ft.) on the pinion shaft with the tires on the ground? Would that hurt anything? Is there any reason I must place the axle on jack stands with the tires off the ground? If I am correct, having the tires on ground will prevent the pinion shaft from moving and thus help me torque the pinion nut.

Comment: Oops, I realized I will need the wheels off the ground to measure preload.

Comment: And oops again...turns out I don't even need to remove pinion yoke. This driveshaft has a flange to mount to the OEM pinion flange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough clearance to fit under the Wrangler, there's no mechanical reason you cannot do this while the vehicle is on the ground. Torquing the pinion nut with it on the ground will not cause any issue to the differential.